# Python for Network Engineers - calling a Python script from a Tkinter GUI window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pyqt4

I wrote a script that prompts a user to paste in a list of items.  Those Items are then stored as a list and used to search through config files for a match on each item in the list.

When there is a match, my script takes the information and formats it to a command line argument for a cisco router; for example:

If a user enters OSPF 10, my script will search a directory for all the router configs that have OSPF 10.  I then reformat the search and print it out as such:

```
router name
-----------
config t
router ospf 10
router-id loopback 0
```

I took my script and made it into an executable file so my users don't have to have python on their machines in order to use it.  When the program is executed, it uses a windows shell screen, which I would like to change.

**The Problem I Need Solved:**

How can I use Tkinter (or Pyqt4) for my users to enter their data, then have the output sent to the gui screen, instead of using a windows shell?  I've read through many blogs, and watched many vids on youtube, but I can't seem to find anything that goes beyond buttons and menus.

I don't have any code yet, because I really don't have a clue where to start.  I get the button and window layout options, but I need more than what I can find.  I'm willing to accept that I might need to read further, so I'm willing to work for the help if needed; but I could really use a good helping hand.

In the meantime, I'll continue reading.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you're trying to call an external script/program, capture the output of that script/program, and then show it in your Python tkinter GUI window? If that's the case, have you looked at [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)?

Comment: @user3030010, I have, but I cant seem to find where I would be able to allow user input, then give me the output I need.  I also am not sure (after some simple testing) I'll be able to bundle my Tkinter GUI and my script into an executable.  Lastly, I was looking more towards importing my script into my Tkinter (or Pyqt4) program, but I need to read more in order to do that; if it can even give me the results i'm looking for.

Comment: Do you need to give user input interactively, or can you pipe it in all at once? Either way, that should be doable with subprocess.communicate() or just by printing data to the .stdin attribute of the Popen object (as if it were a file). As for importing your script into the tkinter application, I don't have much experience with that so I'm afraid I can't help you there.

Comment: @user3030010, Yes, the idea is for my users to be able to put anything (cisco config wise) in my script, and it will return with all the routers that contain that string; I then format an output to a print out of the command structure that created that string.  I will take a look at subprocess and Popen.  I've read a little on it, but admittedly, I need to read some more.  This is really the first time i've every tried to "gui" anything....lol

Comment: @user3030010, i've been reading up on Popen, and although that may be a good start, i think i'm going to have a problem where I need my program to prompt for an input from the user.  I've been thinking about importing my script and using a call as input widget, then the resulting output would be the methods from my imported object.  For example; i would import my script as, from router script import SearchFunction.  Then call SearchFunction.userinput and then have SearchFunction.output put data in frame (in theory)